# Is it possible to edit the elasticsearch.yml file with a script

Tags: python, elasticsearch, filebeat, pyyaml

I am working on a script to automate an ELK stack setup.  I cant seem to find or understand any documentation on editing the yaml files using script (shell or Python).

Is this even possible?

Example:  Let's say i want to enable filebeat.inputs and under type: log I want to set enabled: true

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: false
```

Worth mentioning that [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/override-filebeat-config-settings.html) shows that you can override the configuration for configuration settings and modules, but it states that this does not change the configuration file.

This gets close, but I want to change/ set the configuration file.  Any ideas, advice, or reference to docs is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there an issue with modifying this file with vi editor? Or do you want to do this only via a shell script?

Comment: There are multiple `yq` tools (one of which is a wrapper around `jq` and one which isn't).

Comment: And, well, `pyyaml` is right there in the tags, so you know it exists. "Use pyyaml to load the data, edit it, then save it" is... well, obvious on its face?

Comment: Can you ask a _specific question_ that shows a problem you had when using one of the several preexisting tools for the job?

Comment: I am trying to make this automated.  that includes setting all of the xxx.yml files for elasticsearch, kibana, logstash, filebeat, packetbeat, metricbeat, auditbeat.

Comment: Rather than trying to *edit* this file, you should be *generating* it from a template. There are a wide variety of templating tools out there, which you use is a personal choice and may depend on the environment in which you are running.

Comment: Use an Ansible playbook with Jinja2 templates for that.